# C incomplete type predefined data structure

Tags: c, queue, scheduler, rounding

Hello I am relatively new to C programming. Here is my problem:

I am trying to use a predefined generic queue structure from a header file that is included in my test.c one. However, when I try to use that structure and the functions defined in the header, I get errors associated with 'incomplete type' and I cannot figure out what exactly the compiler does not 'see'.

Here is my header:

```
#ifndef __GENERIC_QUEUE
#define __GENERIC_QUEUE

typedef struct gqueue GQueue;
typedef void *GQueueElement;

GQueue *create_gqueue (void); 
int destroy_gqueue(GQueue *gq);
```

Here is the .c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "generic_queue.h"
#include "TCB.h"

void main(){
    GQueue *qp;
    qp = malloc(sizeof(GQueue));
    qp = *create_gqueue();
    printf("created");

}
```

Here is what I get when compiling:

```
$ gcc test1.c
test1.c: In function ‘main’:
test1.c:8:24: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘GQueue’
  qp = malloc(sizeof(GQueue));
                    ^
test1.c:9:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  qp = *create_gqueue();
```

Comment: in file generic_queue.h

Comment: Based on your error, the source file you posted and the one you are compiling are clearly not the same.

Comment: Oh sorry for misleading you, that .h file is all I have.

Comment: Most likely, you just need to replace the invalid `qp = malloc(sizeof(GQueue)); qp = *create_gqueue();` with a simple `qp = create_gqueue();`. You don't need a complete type if functions are provided for you to perform the operations which need it.

Comment: I tried that already:

    $ gcc test1.c
    /tmp/ccqxs0cE.o:test1.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `create_gqueue'
    /tmp/ccqxs0cE.o:test1.c:(.text+0xe): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `create_gqueue'
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /tmp/ccqxs0cE.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata'
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @user3242807: Well, either you have to also compile the source file with those functions defined in it, or link to the library which contains them, the compiler won't create them by magic.

Comment: Yes but we are not provided that file. Does this seem logical?

Comment: Not if they expect you to be able to produce a working program. You should have been given another source file, or a library.

Comment: I only managed to find an object file generic_queue.o but I do not see how it can help me.

Comment: That's your object file with the functions in it, you need to link them together, e.g. `gcc -o test.o test.c -c` then `gcc -o myprog test.o generic_queue.o`.

Comment: The .c file now compiled in its output object file but then I got

$ gcc -o test1 test1.o generic_queue.o
    generic_queue.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Maybe it was compiled with another compiler, or on a different system.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow on a linux machine, please stay tuned and thank you for your responses so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What appears to be the problem is that though

```
typedef struct gqueue GQueue;
```

defines GQueue to be used instead of struct gqueue, that struct is itself not defined.  Perhaps you need

```
#include "gqueue.h"
```

If the definition of the struct is not included, then you can not use sizeof(GQueue) because the size is not known to the compiler.  However, the program can still compile and run with GQueue being opaque, so long as you use only the exported interface.  It does appear you don't need to even create a GQueue with malloc; you can simply call create_gqueue.

```
qp = malloc(sizeof(GQueue));   // <---- not necessary
qp = create_gqueue();         // <---- all you need
```

Comment: Well, I do not have that file this is a lab exercise and I am given only this generic queue .h file.

Comment: He'll need to lose the `*` before `create_gqueue()` if he wants it to compile, though.

Comment: True, I cut-n-pasted too much.